# Prevent pasting -, +, --, ++, +- into input number

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS, how can I prevent pasting an invalid value of an `<input type="number" />`.
For example, I can prevent pressing - + e E button, but users can paste `2--2` into the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onPaste attribute.

```
const customFunc(e) => {
       if(e.target.value !=null){
              if(!e.target.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   e.stopPropagation();
               }
        }
}


//Use custom function to selectively choose input
<input type="number" onPaste={(event) => this.customFunc(event)} />
```

Comment: Neither of those are valid JSX for React.